# Need Help in Segue Creation

Tags: objective-c, ios7, segue

i am building a app for ios and i have a navbar button with will show user a uialertview with 2 buttons one for cancel and second one to to perform segue when user press cancel he will stay on the same page but when he press yas want to leave he will come to previous viewcontroller

here is the code of .m file

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" message:@"Are You Sure??" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];

    [alert show];

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if ([title isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {

        segueShouldOccur = YES;

    }

}

- (BOOL) shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender{

 if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"perform"]) {

 if (!segueShouldOccur) {

     return NO;

    }

 }

    return YES;

 }
```

when i compile this code it excute alert view shows but then nothing even i press yess or no it stays on same page. please help.

Comment: this is a good start for you http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"YES"]){
    //YES is pressed , perform segue!
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"perform" sender:self];   
    }  
}
```

EDIT, you have to set the deleguate to self not nil

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" 
                                                    message:@"Are You Sure??" 
                                                   delegate:self //set the delegate !
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];

    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: i tried this one but situation is still same. stays on same page.. THANKS for your response

Comment: @user2966615 make sure you have `UIAlertViewDelegate` on your interface

Comment: @user2966615 are you sure your segue id is set to "perform"

Comment: get rid of `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`  you don't need it at all

Comment: Thanks, i updated the code and removed the shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier but it is still stuck on the same page evening if i tap YES.

Answer (score 0):

Your not actually calling the segue to 'occur' - merely setting a Bool to allow it to happen. (You should be calling performSegueWithIdentifier: sender:)